# Let ASP.NET SelectParameters accept null value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have one page to view all Universities,and I want this page to view filtered data as per city, I added to SQL statement:

```
WHERE (Cit_Id = @Unv_CitId OR @Unv_CitId IS NULL)
```

and set DefaultValue of @Unv_CitId parameter to NULL, but I got error,

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What is the error ? please share full query instead of just `where` clause.

Comment: Show us the exception you are receiving.

Answer (score 3):

You should assign value `DBNull.Value` rather then `null`.

Comment: Thanks, however I got this error "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'DB.Null' to data type int."

Comment: I think you don't need 'OR @Unv_CitId IS NULL' part of your query.

Comment: and change it to the DBNull.Value rather then DBNull.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
where (Cit_Id = isdbnull(@Unv_CitId)?null:@unv_citId
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure of your intention, but what about something like this:

```
WHERE (Cit_Id = @Unv_CitId OR Cit_Id IS NULL)
```

Your original query looks a little odd with `@Unv_CitId IS NULL` in there: this clause isn't checking against a field, merely against the value being passed in.

Answer (score 0):

Yes now it is ok, 
I set SqlDataSource's CancelSelectOnNullParameter property to False, and delete the defaultValue of the parameter

Answer (score 0):

delclare @Unv_CitId as null while declaring parameter in procedure as shown below

```
@Unv_CitId int NULL
```

so the varibale will accept null value as well.